# RegEx "ignores" quantifier?

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I have the following string: `http:/www.-woejfewiofjewow`
which is NOT allowed to be matched

My Regex: `http://(www\.[^-])?[^-].*`

(I used `regexr.com` to check it..)

The thing is, it doesn't use the first part of the regex `(www\.[^-])?` but the second part: `[^-].*`

I don't really know how to solve this problem, is there any possibility?

I am trying to search valid URLs (well in this case without .com) with the following format: `http://www.test` `http://test`

Hyphens at the beginning are not allowed (but `http://www.test-test` is allowed)

I am trying to find a solution without lookaheads

Comment: I think your question needs to become more concrete / precise. What are you after ? Do you search for a regex that recognizes valid "hostnames" ?

Comment: You are looking for `www.` followed by NOT `-`, but then you use the quantifier `?` which means *zero or one times*. Just remove the `?`: `http:\/\/(www\.[^-])[^-].*`

Comment: @Marged Yes i am searching for valid HTTP URLs and I've got the most part of the regex except the "Hyphen at the beginning" (with www) which is probably caused because of the second part of the regex ([^-].*)

Comment: @MattBurland I forgot to mention that (ignore underscore) "_http://test" (without www) is also valid

Comment: Note that a URL can return the `hostname` and you could just check to see if it starts with a `-`.

Comment: @user3549524 depending on where you want to run your regex you should perhaps consider that country specific characters (in Germany we have ü and ö) are allowed to be put into the hostname part of a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually need a negative lookahead assertion.

```
\bhttp:\/\/(?!www\.-)[^-].*
```

`(?!www\.-)` negative lookahead which asserts that the double forward_slashes `//` must not be followed by `www.-`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rE9iJ0/1)

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there any way to do it without lookaheads?

Comment: it won't be possible without lookahead. If you use this, `http:\/\/(?:www\.[^-])[^-].*`, it won't match strings like `http://woejfewiofjewow`

Comment: Why does it exactly say that the double forward slashes must not be followed by www.- and not http://?

Comment: Ah alright, sorry.. I didn't want to correct you or something, just thought lookaheads have some conditions :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to validate urls, this regex would match a url a bit better:

```
http:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:[a-zA-z0-9]+)\.(?:[a-z]){2,3}
```

these urls are allowed:

```
http://www.woejfewiofjewow.net
http://www.woejfewiofjewow.ly
```

this is not allowed:

```
http://www.woejfewiofjewow.neta
http://www.woejfewiofjewow.n
```

or even this

```
http://www.-woejfewiofjewow.net
```